# How does ForeignKey decides for the reference?

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

> Here is my django model

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name = 'students',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

> In the above code, ForeignKey of Student class is referencing to name of School class.How is it deciding for the reference while there is no primary key decided in School class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Django will add an id field for your model automatically. Here's an example from the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#quick-example).